# VS Code Unable to open changes for any .ipynb

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever i want to open the changes via the built-in VS Code source control for any Jupyter Notebook (*.ipynb) the changes open but immediately close again. This also happens in a newly created git respository.
It had worked for me in the past, but i can't pinpoint to the exact update.

VS Code version: 1.49
[GIF example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiTOb.gif)

Comment: There is some workaround - Its possible to temporary disable Python extension, check diffs, and enable Python extension again.

Comment: @Jan Thanks, that worked for me. On another system it seems to be working since the latest patch.